# How to effectively sort utf8 string as lexicographic order in cpp

Tags: c++, sorting, utf-8

I want to read an utf-8 file and sort the first line as lexicographic order.

Normally I can sort string as their ASCII values since they already sorted as lexicographic order. However when I use UTF-8 things get messy. `"şğöIä"` etc are no sorted in ASCII code.

I'm using [utfcpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net) library to read my text file. However I cannot find how to order UTF-8 string.

> Input will be like: sşaf
>
> Output will be like: afsş

I thought that I can assign a string constant variable like

```
const string letters = "ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZabcçdefgğhıijklmnoöprsştuüvyz";
```

Then I can check the index of letters to find lexicographic order of that letter to sort.

Is there any better or easier approach that can solve my problem?

Comment: Use a library with UTF8-aware sorting functions? Or internally use UTF32?

Comment: I really suggest a library.  I naive approach like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f6b1dc62573cb59) doesn't work well.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for your code. Actually that gives me Idea even if I will write my code with library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you give me the internal library link please? I'm struggiling to find it :(

Comment: Keep in mind that different human languages order the same characters differently. That's why each language has its own "collation rules". (wikipedia: "For example, in German dictionaries the word ökonomisch comes between offenbar and olfaktorisch, while Turkish dictionaries treat o and ö as different letters, placing oyun before öbür.") https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation